# How do I make ido switch to the buffer suggested by the tab-completion candidate?

Tags: buffers, ido, flx-ido

I use `ido` for switching buffers, and it is awesome. I also have `(flx-ido mode t)` in [my init file](https://github.com/501st-alpha1/emacs/blob/master/init.el#L457).

I have run into a problem that causes me to switch to a buffer different from what I was expecting. I will explain with an example:

Say I have two buffers, `EmacsBuffer`, and `EightyMegabytesAndConstantlySwapping`. I switch to a different buffer, e.g. `*scratch*`, and now I want to get back to `EmacsBuffer`, so I do `C-x b` and start typing: `e m a c`... This is what I see:

```
Buffer: emac[sBuffer]{EightyMegabytesAndConstantlySwapping}
EmacsBuffer
```

As you can see, the candidate for tab-completion is `EmacsBuffer`, as I would expect. However, because I have `flex` enabled, the other buffer is fuzzy-matched, and so it is the candidate to immediately switch to. Since I usually am looking only at what I am typing, I see that `EmacsBuffer` is the candidate for tab-completion, so I immediately hit `RET`, and am surprised when it switches to `EightyMegabytesAndConstantlySwapping`. How do I change this so that the immediate-switch buffer is the same as the tab-completion buffer?

I could just disable `flex`, but I do find it useful, because e.g. if I don't have a buffer named `EmacsBuffer`, I like that `e m a c s` matches `EightyMegabytesAndConstantlySwapping`.

Comment: Looks like the behavior of `flx-ido-mode` is to favor the longest match. I don't see a straightforward way to tweak this behavior.

Comment: Not a real answer, but might solve your problem: Is it viable to give one of these files different names?

Comment: @Malabarba Not really. I gave a simplified example, but in practice it happens even for things that may not be acronyms. Also, with the amount of files I have open on a regular basis, it will be pretty hard to guarantee that there isn't a conflict somewhere.

Comment: Maybe you can bind RET to send TAB and RET in the ido completion map. Not sure what that might break, though.

Comment: @glucas That could work. I think the combination of your two comments are worthy of an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the source, `flx-ido-mode` favors the longest potential match. There aren't any options to tune this behavior.

You might be able to get what you want by tweaking the ido key bindings. Ido has a few different key maps, so depending on exactly what you want you could modify `ido-common-completion-map`, `ido-file-completion-map`, or `ido-buffer-completion-map`.

A couple thoughts:

- You could add an ido binding to toggle `flx-ido-mode` on and off. Perhaps leave it off by default and toggle it on when you need it. This seems to work:

  ```
  ;; always start ido with flx matching off
  (add-hook 'ido-setup-hook (lambda () (flx-ido-mode -1)))

  ;; toggle flx matching without writing to the minibuffer
  (defun quietly-toggle-flx-ido-mode ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((minibuffer-message-timeout 0))
      (flx-ido-mode 'toggle)))

  ;; define a key to toggle flx matching while in ido
  (define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "<f8>") #'quietly-toggle-flx-ido-mode)
  ```
- You could rebind RET to first trigger tab completion. I haven't played with this, but something like:

  ```
  (defun ido-complete-and-exit ()
    (interactive)
    (ido-complete)
    (ido-exit-minibuffer))

  (define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "RET") #'ido-complete-and-exit)
  ```

**EDIT**

As noted in the comments, the second example above does not work. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with ido internals to propose a solution along these lines that doesn't break other ido behavior.

The best solution would be to revise how flx sorts the candidates. I see some open issues along these lines, e.g. https://github.com/lewang/flx/issues/63.

Comment: Hmm.. the code you gave doesn't seem to work (no errors though). I'll hack at it for a while and report back if I get it working.

Comment: Yeah, I see that -- sorry! I tried using ido-select-text instead of ido-exit-minibuffer. That works for this one test case, but I think it'll break when tab-completion yields more than one candidate.

Comment: Yeah that did the same thing for me. It also didn't work when switching directly to the previous buffer (e.g. `C-x b RET`).

Comment: Accepted this answer, though I will keep hacking at it to see if I can get the second solution to work, because I think that would be ideal (after having the root cause fixed of course).